# Got "Unable to parse YAML error" when converting JSON to yml

Tags: json, yaml, converters, pyyaml

I use [JSON converter to YML](https://www.json2yaml.com/) format. It works fine.

But the result is invalid YAML checked by [Validate YAML](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator)

One of error:

```
Error: Unable to parse.
Line: 36    - Ref: ALIYUN::StackId
```

Please help me convert to valid YML from JSON. Thanks.

My JSON file:

```
{
  "ROSTemplateFormatVersion": "2015-09-01",
  "Resources": {
    "k8s_node_cloudinit_wait_cond": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ROS::WaitCondition",
      "Properties": {
        "Count": "1",
        "Handle": {
          "Ref": "k8s_node_cloudinit_wait_cond_handle"
        },
        "Timeout": 1000
      }
    },
    "k8s_sg": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ECS::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "Priority": 1,
            "IpProtocol": "all",
            "NicType": "internet",
            "SourceCidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "PortRange": "-1/-1"
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_vpc"
        },
        "SecurityGroupEgress": [
          {
            "Priority": 1,
            "IpProtocol": "all",
            "DestCidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "NicType": "internet",
            "PortRange": "-1/-1"
          }
        ],
        "SecurityGroupName": "k8s_sg"
      }
    },
    "SubAccount": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::RAM::User",
      "Properties": {
        "UserName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "SubAccount",
              {
                "Ref": "ALIYUN::StackId"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "k8s_node_cloudinit_wait_cond_handle": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ROS::WaitConditionHandle"
    },
    "ECSManagePolicy": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::RAM::ManagedPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "ECSManagePolicy",
              {
                "Ref": "ALIYUN::StackId"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "1",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": [
                "*"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                "*"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow"
            },
            {
              "Action": [
                "vpc:DescribeVpcs",
                "vpc:DescribeVSwitches"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                "*"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Users": [
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "SubAccount",
              "UserName"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AccessKey": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::RAM::AccessKey",
      "Properties": {
        "UserName": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "SubAccount",
            "UserName"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "k8s_master": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ECS::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Replace": [
            {
              "ros-notify": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "k8s_master_cloudinit_wait_cond_handle",
                  "CurlCli"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "#!/bin/sh\n",
                  "until yum -y install expect || ! cat /etc/os-release|grep centos; do echo 'wait yum ready ...'; sleep 1; done\n",
                  "curl -sSL http://aliacs-k8s.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/installer/kubemgr-1.7.2.sh | ",
                  "bash -s nice --node-type master --oss-region ap-southeast-1 --key-id ",
                  {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "AccessKey",
                      "AccessKeyId"
                    ]
                  },
                  " --key-secret ",
                  {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "AccessKey",
                      "AccessKeySecret"
                    ]
                  },
                  "\n",
                  "TOKEN=`kubeadm token list | grep token |awk '{print $1}'`\n",
                  "ros-notify -d \"{\\\"data\\\": \\\"$TOKEN\\\"}\" \n"
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "SystemDiskCategory": "cloud_ssd",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_vpc"
        },
        "SecurityGroupId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_sg"
        },
        "ImageId": "centos_7",
        "VSwitchId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_vswitch"
        },
        "IoOptimized": "optimized",
        "Password": "abcABC@147896325",
        "InstanceType": "ecs.n1.medium",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "192.168.0.1"
      }
    },
    "k8s_vswitch": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ECS::VSwitch",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_vpc"
        },
        "CidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/16",
        "ZoneId": {
          "Fn::Select": [
            "0",
            {
              "Fn::GetAZs": {
                "Ref": "ALIYUN::Region"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "k8s_master_cloudinit_wait_cond": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ROS::WaitCondition",
      "Properties": {
        "Count": 1,
        "Handle": {
          "Ref": "k8s_master_cloudinit_wait_cond_handle"
        },
        "Timeout": 900
      }
    },
    "k8s_nodes": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ECS::InstanceGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Replace": [
            {
              "ros-notify": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "k8s_node_cloudinit_wait_cond_handle",
                  "CurlCli"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "Fn::Join": [
                "",
                [
                  "#!/bin/sh\n",
                  "until yum -y install expect || ! cat /etc/os-release|grep centos; do echo 'wait yum ready ...'; sleep 1; done\n",
                  "export TOKEN=`echo '",
                  {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "k8s_master_cloudinit_wait_cond",
                      "Data"
                    ]
                  },
                  "' | awk -F '\"' '{print $4}'`\n",
                  "curl -sSL http://aliacs-k8s.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/installer/kubemgr-1.7.2.sh | ",
                  "bash -s nice --node-type node --oss-region ap-southeast-1 --key-id ",
                  {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "AccessKey",
                      "AccessKeyId"
                    ]
                  },
                  " --key-secret ",
                  {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "AccessKey",
                      "AccessKeySecret"
                    ]
                  },
                  " --token $TOKEN ",
                  " --endpoint 192.168.0.1:6443\n",
                  "num=$(cat /dev/urandom | head -n 10 | cksum | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')\n",
                  "seconds=$(($num%30))\n",
                  "sleep $seconds\n",
                  "ros-notify -d \"{\\\"data\\\": \\\"$TOKEN\\\"}\" \n"
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "SystemDiskCategory": "cloud_ssd",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_vpc"
        },
        "MinAmount": "1",
        "SecurityGroupId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_sg"
        },
        "ImageId": "centos_7",
        "VSwitchId": {
          "Ref": "k8s_vswitch"
        },
        "IoOptimized": "optimized",
        "Password": "abcABC@147896325",
        "InstanceType": "ecs.n1.medium",
        "MaxAmount": "1"
      }
    },
    "k8s_master_cloudinit_wait_cond_handle": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ROS::WaitConditionHandle"
    },
    "k8s_vpc": {
      "Type": "ALIYUN::ECS::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcName": "k8s_vpc",
        "CidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/16"
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "k8s_master_token": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "k8s_master_cloudinit_wait_cond",
          "Data"
        ]
      }
    },
    "DashboardURL": {
      "Description": "Kubernetes dashboard URL.",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "http://",
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "k8s_master",
                "PublicIp"
              ]
            },
            ":80"
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "k8s_node_token": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "k8s_node_cloudinit_wait_cond",
          "Data"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using that validator, it claims to be the best, but it actually doesn't confirm to YAML 1.2 nor YAML 1.1.

The YAML line about which it complains (36) is:

```
         - Ref: ALIYUN::StackId
```

and one of the things that broken validator cannot deal with is colons within unquoted scalar strings (i.e. in `ALIYUN::StackId`). Since the colons that are not followed by a space or (in YAML 1.2) preceded and followed by a double quote, **never** indicate a key-value pair, there is no confusion possible with this valid YAML.

Just try to load the output of the convert in PyYAML, or paste it on [this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) site (which is based on PyYAML), you'll see that there are no problems. Although PyYAML is not perfect either (and only supports most of YAML 1.1) that is a much better validation than the site that you have been using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use YAML template to work with Alibaba Cloud ROS, and not pass the validation. So, I must validate the template. Any suggestion for me more?

Answer (score 0):

I use [json2yaml package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2yaml) to convert JSON to YML, it works fine.